# Dynamically creating a service-activator in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have a web service that will have several versions and multiple classes per version.  I want to create the service activators dynamically at startup so I can lessen the amount of configuration so maintenance is easier.  A developer can drop in a new class and SI would automatically pick it up.

I coded up an ApplicationListener:

```
public class SpringContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ApplicationListener Invoked At Spring Container Startup");

                String s = "com.ps.snt.MyClass";
                Class c = Class.forName(s);

                ServiceActivatingHandler serviceActivator;
                serviceActivator = new ServiceActivatingHandler(c.newInstance());
                serviceActivator.setComponentName("MyClassBean");
                // also tried setBeanName
        }
}
```

Later on in a router, I have the following code:

```
protected Collection<MessageChannel> determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message) {

        List<MessageChannel> channels = new ArrayList<MessageChannel>();

        MessageChannel channel = (MessageChannel)this.getBeanFactory().getBean("MyClassBean", ServiceActivatingHandler.class);
        channels.add(channel);
        return channels;
    }
```

But I get the following error when the router tries to route:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'MyClassBean' is defined
```

Any thoughts on how I would do this?  I need to dynamically create the service activators and route messages to these later.

The following works if I put it in the configuration:

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="MyClassBean">
        <bean class="com.ps.snt.ws.MyClassBean" />
    </int:service-activator>
```

There is no way to set the input-channel on ServiceActivatingHandler, so do I need to create a channel with the same name and subscribe the activator to it?  Here is that code, and still received the same error:

```
String s = "com.ps.snt.MyClass";
Class c = Class.forName(s);

DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
channel.setBeanName("MyClassBean");

ServiceActivatingHandler serviceActivator;
serviceActivator = new ServiceActivatingHandler(c.newInstance());

channel.subscribe(serviceActivator);
```

UPDATE: I had to register the bean after creating the channel.  THis code did the trick:

```
DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
channel.setBeanName("MyClassBean");

ServiceActivatingHandler serviceActivator;
serviceActivator = new ServiceActivatingHandler(c.newInstance());

channel.subscribe(serviceActivator);

ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).getBeanFactory();
beanFactory.registerSingleton("MyClassBean", channel);
```

My new question: Is this an OK approach or will it cause issues down the line?

Answer (score 0):

If it is supposed to be dynamic / runtime, then you would not be hard coding SA bean class names.

If you can throw some insights into your deployment and runtime environment, may be I can suggest better ways.  Your objective is not clear (developer can drop in SA class and SI would pick it up automatically).

Comment: Basically, I have 6 service endpoints (POJOs) that need to  process messages.  These will be versioned, so the amount of configuration will increase each time we add a new version (set of POJOs).  I also need logic in place to deprecate versions.  So, to make maintenance easier, I create the channels and service activators at startup, by using reflection and inspecting the service endpoint directory.  The assumption is that only endpoints are located in this folder.  The channel name is set such that the router can route messages to it based on some header values.