# Create a constant field at Runtime in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

My constant will pick a value from the environment variable, which is used in the error channel of Spring Cloud's Service Activator.

Service activator takes a constant value :

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
```

I am trying to read properties file and use it in my error channel, since my consumer group is different for different cloud environments..

```
@Value("${consumer.group.name}")
    private String name;

private final String error_ch = "topic."+name+".errors"
```

But the Service activator rejects error_ch.

How can i create constants at runtime using environment variables/ properties?

Comment: *Constants* are, by definition, something created at compile-time, so what you're asking is impossible.

Comment: See: [Dynamically creating a service-activator in Spring Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24807032/5221149)

Comment: Rest endpoints are there? RestController?

Comment: @Andreas :  https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/08/hands-on-java-constantdynamic.html